# Operator[] in std::map implementation

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to implement a container like [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) in C++. I have a small query while overloading operator []. I see that this operator works in two ways:

1. `mymap[2]` - For this case it looks for key 2 in map and return the value against this key.
2. `mymap[2]=3` - For this case it looks for key 2 in map and if key is not found than 3 is inserted in map.

I see that declaration for this operator looks like: `Mapped_T &operator[](const Key_T &);` but what I am not getting is that in case the key is not found I will have to insert a new element in Map but in declaration of operator[] function I don't see value being passed anywhere. So how would overloaded operator know what is value against key to be inserted?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: They are both the same case. writing `X = Y` first evaluates `X` and `Y` before performing the assignment, and `X` is evaluated the same way regardless of context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the key does not exist, `std::map` constructs a new value using the value class's default constructor, and returns a reference to the newly-inserted value.

Comment: But in this case how would actual value be inserted against that key?

Comment: As I explained to you: the actual value is constructed using the object's default constructor, and inserted. For simple types, the default constructor is zero-initialization.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still not getting it. If I call mymap[2]=3 (assume key doesn't exists for now, then
1. overloaded operator for [] is called
2. Key 2 is inserted with some default value assume it is NULL for now.
But in this whole process how is 5 inserted?

Comment: The default value is 0. And where did 5 come from? There's no 5 here. Key 2 is inserted with the value of 0, `operator[]` then returns a reference to this value, and the `=` operator assigns 3 to it.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted. It's a valid answer.

Answer (score 3):

It would be value-initialized - as if with `{}`, here's some pseudocode:

```
Mapped_T & operator[](const Key_T &k) {
    if(!has_key(k))
        insert(k, Mapped_T{});
    return at(k);
}
```

The important part for your question is `Mapped_T{}`. For aggregates it means zero-initialization, for classes with default constructor it means using that constructor.

Comment: So you mean intializer_list would be called to copy the actual value against the key in map?

Comment: No, there's no `initializer_list` anywhere in this code.